# Passing data from first activities to a second , second activity to third activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a total of 3 activites. I pass the data from the first activity :
Here's My `AsyncTask parseResult` method

```
    private void parseResult(String result) {
        try {

            Log.d("MainActivity", "JSON Result : " + result);
            JSONArray response = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)

            {

                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String movie_d = obj.getString("newsD");


                String movie_t = obj.getString("newsT");

                String movie_i = obj.getString("newsI");


                String movie_s_link=obj.getString("newsS");

                String movie_youtube_link=obj.getString("youtubeLink");

                Log.d("movie_youtube_link","JSON Result : " + result);



                String movie_rev_r=obj.getString("reviewR");

                Log.d("documentName","JSON Result : " + result);

                Newspojo rev_gd = new Newspojo();


                rev_gd.setNewsDescription(movie_dec);

                rev_gd.setNewsT(movie_t);
                rev_gd.setNewsI(movie_i);
                rev_gd.setNewsS(movie_source_l);
                rev_gd.setYoutubeLink(movie_youtube_link);
                rev_gd.setReviewR(movie_rev_r);
                revData.add(rev_gd);


            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In my first activity I am displaying a `ListView`. When I click a list item at current position i am displaying some fields in `Activity` 2

I send bundle data when i click a list position. Here's my `onClick` listener in list position

**FirstActivity**

```
reviewlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mov_pos", position + "");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return rootview;
}
```

Here my position OnClick  was working fine. I'm trying to display some fields in Second `Activity`

**Second Activity:**

Here i pass some values it was displaying fine my problem is when i bundle my youtubeLink link to the third `Activity`. I am getting null values , I checked youtubeLink
value and I am getting it from the server and parsing it in `TextView` okay but my problem is when i bundle youtubeLink from second `Activity` to third `Activity`. I am getting null value.

```
 static String youtubeLink;



    youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();


    Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
            youtubeLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    movie_t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movietitle);

    rev_r=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movierev_sitename);


    movie_d=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_moviedisc_text);

    //youtube video text static text (video)
    youtube_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieyoutube_text);



    movie_i=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieImage);

    //youtube image display id and imageView
    youtube_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.revi_fulldes_movieyoutubeImg);
    youtube_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent youtube = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayYouTube1st.class);
            youtube.putExtra("youtubeLink", youtubeLink);
            startActivity(youtube);
            // Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
            // youtubeLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });


    mov_pos = Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("mov_pos"));


    movie_t.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getNewsT());


    rev_r.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getReviewR());


    movie_d.setText(Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getNewsD());
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load((Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos)).getNewsI()).into(target);




}
```

**Here's my ThirdActivity:**

```
private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
String youLink;


Intent intent =getIntent();
    youLink=intent.getStringExtra("youtubeLink");
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    Toast.makeText(PlayYouTube1st.this,
            youLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I have been stuck on this error for the past 2 days so could please someone help me find why  youtubeLink  is showing null values when passing it to 3rd Activity? Thank you!

Comment: when you are starting Activity from 2nd activity did you check the value of youtubeLink?

Comment: yes it displaying null@sankyjain

Comment: is it correct this way asingn for getting youtubeLink values

    youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();

Comment: so your problem is youtubeLink is null in 2nd activity. In that case please show the code for youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();

Comment: actually when i show in textview youtubeLink it working fine when i use this getting null value youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();@sankyjain

Comment: i post all my code above please look @sankyjain

Comment: i want to see code for Reviews_update

Comment: yes that code is firsactivty and parseResult @sankyjain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104817/discussion-between-sanky-jain-and-chanti).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below line

```
mov_pos = Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("mov_pos"));
```

above

```
youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();
```